# how to replace a known substring value in a string variable

Tags: perl

I have a string that looks like the following:

```
prop_1=val1 prop_2=val2 prop_3=val3
```

I want to replace the entirety of one of the tokens so the string looks like:

```
prop_1=val1 prop_X=valX prop_3=val3
```

I have tried

```
$params =~ s/prop_2=val2/prop_X=valX/ig;
```

but nothing is changing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are mistaken.

```
$params = 'prop_1=val1 prop_2=val2 prop_3=val3';
$params =~ s/prop_2=val2/prop_X=valX/ig;
print "$params\n";
```

gives

```
prop_1=val1 prop_X=valX prop_3=val3
```

You have not demonstrated the problem. The only thing I can think of that could cause the above to fail is if `pos($params)` isn't zero, such as if you perhaps did use `/.../g` in scalar context earlier, as in

```
if ($params =~ /.../g)   # Bad
```

---

Note that `s/(?<!\S)prop_2=val(?!\S)/prop_X=valX/ig` would be better as it won't match `aprop_2=vals`.

Comment: `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` would be simpler as `\b`.

Comment: @Jon Purdy, How can something that gives the wrong result be simpler? (e.g. `foo.prod_2=val`)

Comment: Just giving an alternative. There’s no indication in the question of whether it’s right or wrong, as OP’s examples used only word characters. But “word boundary” is certainly simpler than “not preceded/followed by non-whitespace”.

Comment: @Jon Purdy, I don't see how you can call `(?<!\S)\b` and `\b(?!\S)`, simpler than `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)`.

Comment: I didn’t. Don’t worry about it.

Comment: @Jon Purdy, You're completely missing the point. The Op's code matched in too many places. I suggested he fix that. The only want to fix that using `\b` is by using `(?<!\S)\b` and `\b(?!\S)`, and that's not as simple as `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)`. If he were to just use `\b`, he'd be left with exactly the same problem he already has, so mentioning it is completely wrong or makes unwarranted (and more importantly, unspecified) assumptions.

Comment: @ikegami: I'm afraid it's *you* that's completely missing the point

Comment: @Borodin, How can I miss the point when I'm the one making it? Using `\b` alone would defy it.